# Taking a bath in Adventure mode

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

How do I clean my dwarf and his items in Adventure mode? Currently I've killed a number of things and am covered in blood, leaving a trail of it behind me wherever I walk.

I doubt it'll impress the Queen much if I wander into her hall, leaving a red carpet behind me.

Answer (score 7):

Entering water will clean contaminants such as blood and vomit off you. Lakes, brooks, rivers and seas all work. Keep in mind that if you haven't started with novice swimming skill or better you will likely perish, unless the body of water has sloped sides, in which case you can escape your would-be watery grave via a slope.

Comment: less likely, now that rivers are all sloped.

Comment: @RavenDreamer didn't know that, good to know. I guess novice swimming has been replaced by novice reading as the "kick yourself for not taking it" skill.

Answer (score 4):

In DF2014 (maybe others too) adventure mode you can press **e** (eat) and choose bloody items/body parts. Your dwarf will lick them clean.

Comment: Wait, what? Eating your own bloody limbs, and licking them clean? This is a vulgar game...

Answer (score 2):

Build a dwarf shower!

```
wwww____
_|_w____|____
 |wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

Where W is water, _ are grates in the room, and | are doors.

As long as you keep the water flowing, you get clean dwarves.

Comment: That'll be great for fortress mode. :)

Comment: @MikeyB you could always retire, start a fortress, make a shower (and some leet steel equipment), abandon, then go take your shower.  Should only take a few years ...